# Configure elastic beanstalk to use new version of python

Tags: django, python-2.7, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

How can I tell Amazon Elastic Beanstalk to use Python 2.7.3 when running Django without creating a custom AMI?

It seems like it should be straightforward to tell elastic beanstalk to use a later version of python than 2.6. I would really like to not create a custom AMI, as that seems like over-complicating the issue.

I need python 2.7.3, and I need to use virtualenv 1.8.X. I've noticed that using a later version of virtualenv than the amazon deployment tutorial(1.7.X) seems to negatively affect 'git aws.push', but I don't have an option in this case due to client requirements.

I've looked into creating custom container commands in the .ebextensions/*.config, such as:

```
container_commands:
  update_python:
    command: "sudo yum -y install python27; sudo ln -sf `which python2.7` /usr/bin/python"
```

but this breaks yum, which might be ok, but I'd prefer to keep the system intact.

I could install python27 with yum, as demonstrated above, and keep python26 as the default python, but I don't know how to make sure that the server uses python27 to launch Django. So an alternate question would be, how do I tell elastic beanstalk to use python27 to run Django instead of the default python? I can easily get python27 installed on the system as an alternate python, I just have to call it explicitly.

I hope this question isn't too broad. I'm trying to come up with multiple angles to solve this problem. Thanks for any help.

Comment: If you know where Elastic Beanstalk keeps it's virtualenv python then simply replace that one instead of the real one. I'm not sure about differences in virtualenvs though.

Answer (score -3):

I ran into this exact same problem and the solution was quite simple.

Assuming that your PATH environment variable points to this folder:

```
<path to unzipped EB CLI package>/eb/linux/python2.7/
```

Go there and edit the file named "eb"

```
$cd <path to unzipped EB CLI package>/eb/linux/python2.7/
$vim eb
```

On the first line where it says "*!#/usr/bin/env python*" change it to "*!#/usr/bin/env python2.7*"

And then you should be alright!

Comment: The question is asking about the deployment, not the eb command line tool